# What command line arguments do I need to use SOIL(Simple OpenGL Image Library)?

Tags: opengl, g++, soil

I installed libsoil1. Unfortunately, it's impossible to use without the command line arguments. What do I need to use it with g++?

Also, is the include file #include < SOIL.h >, or is it something else?

I'm using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4):

You need the development files. On Ubuntu you install them using

```
sudo apt-get install libsoil-dev
```

The general rule is, that for every library package, there's a corresponding development files packages of the same name, suffixed with `-dev`.

You need to `#include` the soil headers so that the *compiler* knows which symbols are defined and can be used by your code. The linker itself needs to be told to actually link the libraries used by the `-l…` argument, in the case of SOIL `-lSOIL`.

Comment: How do I include the soil header? Nothing I've tried seems to work, and I can't even find documentation for that.

Comment: `dpkg -L libsoil-dev`